# Set integer attribute based on a text string attribute

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I have an atribute field listing biomes as text strings. I need to do some processing in another program that requires biome information in a numeric code. TLDR; every 'Tropical Rainforest' needs to become '4'. I'd prefer to do this by having an extra Biome Codes field since I could feed the program an exported CSV.

Is there any way other than manually typing?

Comment: Do you have a table with the codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Field Calculator, make a new field set to Whole Number as the data type.

To populate it use a version of the following expression:

```
CASE
   WHEN "biome_name_field" = 'Tropical Rainforest' THEN 4
   WHEN "biome_name_field" = 'Desert' THEN 5
   WHEN "biome_name_field" = 'Tundra' THEN 6
END
```